ROS2 Nav2 Multi-Robot Simulation with shared information between robots
I want to set up a simulation with multiple identical robots which can share information between them. i.e.: current pose of the robots (so that robot 1 knows where robot 2 and 3 are) and sensor information (letting the other robots know where obstacles are).
Currently, I have setup the simulation such as that three robots are loaded into gazebo and three seperate rviz windows open up where a goal pose can be given to each robot.
I do not really know how or where to start, so that the sensor data and poses are taken into account when path planning.

One idea of mine was to combine the sensor information onto the global costmap which would then be shared to all robots.
Or combine the costmaps of all robots to a single shared costmap

Are those doable solution or is there a better way?
A nudge in the right direction or some good resources would help me a lot.
Thank you.
